# Check Hotmail message was actually sent when session expired while sending

Tags: outlook.com

How would I know my email has been sent through Hotmail when at the time I send the email it said my Hotmail session expired? Would the email appear seen in the send folder?

During the time I was writing my email, the notice read, "Hotmail session expired, connect again," but when I finished writing and pressed the send button, it showed that "message sent" and then it's in the send folder too.

How can I confirm it was actually sent?

Answer (score 1):

If a copy of the e-mail is in your sent items then yes, it has been sent.